# When making a program that draws forever, how do I keep the drawings on screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

It's a fairly simple code I made in my free time, but since it's random the pointer always has a chance of going off screen. I've watched my child use Scratch before and in their drawing/sprites if it hits the edge it can bounce off back in, so it's never off screen. I am looking for a code like that but for Python.

```
from turtle import*
from random import*

while True:
    forward(randint(1, 360))
    right(randint(1, 360))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Turtle to Bounce Off the Walls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482196/getting-turtle-to-bounce-off-the-walls) or [Python3.2 How to keep turtle from going off the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891134/python3-2-how-to-keep-turtle-from-going-off-the-screen-and-when-it-does-reset) or [TurtleGraphics Python: Bouncing turtle off the walls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457332/turtlegraphics-python-bouncing-turtle-off-the-walls)

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import *  
from random import*  

while True:  
    forward(randint(1, 360))
    right(randint(1, 360)) 
    if xcor() < 0:
        setx(20)
    if ycor() < 0:
        sety(20)
    if xcor() > window_width():
        setx(window_width()-20)
    if ycor() > window_height():
        sety(window_height()-20)
```

Should work, where 20 is up to your choice.

Edit: The Solutions in one of the duplicate posts are probably better